# copy paste from Eric IDE does not work

Tags: eric-ide

I am able to copy/paste from Windows or Linux terminal into Eric IDE but not otherwise. Should I install a plugin?

I am using Xming on windows.

Answer (score -1):

I found that the keyboard shortcuts ctrl+c and ctrl+v don't always work for me, however, a right click with the mouse often works for me even when the keyboard shortcuts do not.